# Spring : Logging wont get disabled. Turned to Debug by default

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I have logging. I had kept it disabled as I could see any errors happening in console, and that was enough for me. Today, I added 3 libraries of `JXLS` in POM.xml and since then, logging of entire application somehow got turned on to debug mode. My log4j.xml already says not to log, but it's ignored. I have also added entries in application.properties and indicated the log4j.xml in web.xml, but no use. What am I doing wrong? I tried suggestions from other SO answers, but that didn't help.

log4j.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>


    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.journaldev.spring">
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.security">
        <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="OFF"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="javax.validation">
        <level value="OFF"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator">
        <level value="OFF"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.cometd">
        <level value="OFF"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

added in application.properties as well :

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

in web.xml :

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Entire POM.xml (3 new added dependencies are on top.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>APPNAME</groupId>
    <artifactId>APPNAME</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <spring-platform.version>1.1.3.RELEASE</spring-platform.version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Excel dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jsoup dependency, library to remove hTML tags,
        only used for removing html parts from GroupNote -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
             <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.3</version>
         </dependency>


        <!-- Jasypt dependencies, required for cryptography with hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
   <!--     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--&lt;!&ndash; EverNote API's &ndash;&gt;
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.evernote</groupId>
            <artifactId>evernote-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Microsoft translator API's -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.memetix</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-translator-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Icalendar dependencies, library required to generate ICS files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Google drive dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev175-1.18.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev92-1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google plus dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev216-1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Dropbox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>[1.7,1.8)</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate search dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cometd dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>bayeux-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.9.v20150224</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Thumbnail dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>


     <!-- Apache dependencies-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Aspectj is over here -->

        <!-- Joda Date & Time dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IText dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jackson dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgresql or database dependencies-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
             <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
         </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.4</version>
                 <executions>
                    <execution>
                          <id>default-minify</id>
<!--                          <phase>package</phase> -->
                          <configuration>
                            <charset>UTF-8</charset>

                          </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Check your application server's log4j config. It is probably getting overridden.

Comment: @Bnrdo : I have Apache tomcat 7.0.67.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`logback.xml`** to **`src/main/resources`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

  <logger name="org.somecompany" level="INFO"/>
  <logger name="com.your.lib" level="OFF"/>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Where should I put this file? Also, I am not using Spring-boot. It's a Spring-MVC project.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. :-) Any suggestion on cleaning upon the POM.xml for logging dependencies?